# NUnit Setup Method not using new values handed in

Tags: c#, nunit, tdd, moq, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to get better with TDD and implement some unit tests using NUnit for a desk booking application. My Setup is as follows...

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    deskBookingRequest = new DeskBookingRequest
    {
        FirstName = "Alex",
        LastName = "Barry",
        Email = "test.email@hotmail.com",
        Date = new DateTime(2022, 8, 28)
    };

    availableDesks = new List<Desk>() { new Desk() };
    _databaseService.Setup(x => x.GetDesks(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns(availableDesks);
}
```

I'm trying to create a scenario in which the `.GetDesks` method would return null which would cause the `.Save` method to never be called. I figured I could do something like the following (in where the `.GetDesks` is called within `.BookDesk`...

```
[Test]
public void ShouldNotSaveDeskIfNoneAreAvailable()
{
    //Arrange
    availableDesks = null;

    //Act
    result = _processor.BookDesk(deskBookingRequest);

    //Assert
    _databaseService.Verify(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<DatabaseSaveBookingRequest>()), Times.Never);
}
```

but `.GetDesks` is still returns a List with one desk object. Would I need to specifically call a new setup method for `.GetDesks` or is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: This is why I hate using setup methods and sharing objects between tests. Just define everything you need inside your test and all these problems go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Setup]`-annotated methods run *before* each test method, so it already sets up the `_databaseService` with the `availableDesks` object. Even when you later null out `availableDesks` in the test, the `_databaseService` has a reference to the original object.

Do yourself the favour and forgo the use of setup methods. They cause all sorts of [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)) problems like the one you are encountering. Instead, write self-contained test methods like this:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldNotSaveDeskIfNoneAreAvailable()
{
    //Arrange
    // ...
    databaseService.Setup(x => x.GetDesks(It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns(null);
    // ...

    //Act
    result = processor.BookDesk(deskBookingRequest);

    //Assert
    databaseService.Verify(
        x => x.Save(It.IsAny<DatabaseSaveBookingRequest>()),
        Times.Never);
}
```

Don't use class fields, but create object within the test methods.

If you are concerned about code duplication, address that concern like you would in any other code base. If you need inspiration or examples, there's [literally an entire book about unit test patterns](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/xunit-patterns).

Comment: I would also define the variables inside the test method too. Not sure if OP made a mistake when copying over, but reusing `result`  might be particularly bad. But I'd be more worried about the `Verify` method cross-contamination.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I think I will just simplify the code as suggested instead of reusing components unnecessarily.